# If file doesn't exist, program fails in C

Tags: c, loops, file-io

This used to work. I don't know what I did to make it stop working but when I enter a file name that does not exist, I get a segment violation error and the program quits.

```
int main()
{
    File *fr;
    char input_file[32];
    int num_lines, valid;

    do{
        printf("\nEnter the name of the input file: ");
        scanf("%s", input_file);
        fr = fopen(input_file, "r");
        if(fr == NULL){
            valid = 0;
            printf("File does not exist...");
        }
        if(fr != NULL){
            fscanf(fr, "%d", &num_lines);
            numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_lines);
            for(i=0;i<num_lines;i++){
                fscanf(fr, "%[^0123456789]%d", numbers+i);
                printf("%d\n", numbers[i]);
                valid =1;
            }
            free(numbers);
            fclose(fr);
        }

    }while(valid == 0);
}
```

**/edited/**

Comment: You never check if the fopen() call succeeded. You then try to read from that non-existent file.

Comment: 'If the file has been successfully opened the function will return a pointer to a FILE object that is used to identify the stream on all further operations involving it. Otherwise, a null pointer is returned.'  Check returns from system calls!

Comment: @MartinJames   what do you mean by 'check returns from system calls'?

Answer (score 3):

Notice the following:

```
fr = fopen(input_file, "r");
fscanf(fr, "%d", &num_lines);
if(fr == NULL){
```

Here, you're passing the result from `fopen` directly into `fscanf` without first testing whether or not the file was opened successfully.  If the file can't be opened, `fr` will be `NULL`, hence the segmentation fault.

Try reordering the code so that you don't do the `fscanf` until you've confirmed that `fr != NULL`.  For example:

```
fr = fopen(input_file, "r");
if(fr != NULL){
    fscanf(fr, "%d", &num_lines);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: no, it didn't really work. it at least printed "file does not exist" now though

Answer (score 3):

Well, this line is very, very wrong:

```
    scanf("%s", input_file[32]);
```

The second argument ought to be a pointer to a character buffer, but you're passing a character value, which could point to  any random location. It might seemingly work OK, but it will corrupt some random spot in memory that you may need for some reason!

Then you go on to pass the result of calling `fopen()` directly to `fscanf()` without checking first to see if it's null; that's not going to work out too well either.

Comment: it didn't really work. it at least printed "file does not exist" now though

Answer (score 1):

You must've moved the `fscanf` call to before checking if `fr==NULL`. You need to move the fscanf to after the `fr==null` check.

Comment: it didn't really work. it at least printed "file does not exist" now though

Answer (score 1):

You must check if `fr` is NULL before call `fscanf(fr, "%d", &num_lines)`
And change the first scanf: `scanf("%s", input_file);`

Answer (score 1):

You should check

```
if(fr == NULL){
   valid = 0;
   printf("File does not exist...");
}
```

before

```
fscanf(fr, "%d", &num_lines);
```